# SQL search merge

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to merge two select sentence. Is it possible ?
I have three tables :

score

```
+------+---------+-------+
| ID   | SUBJECT | SCORE |
+------+---------+-------+
|    1 | Chinese |    65 |
|    1 | English |    75 |
|    2 | Chinese |    60 |
|    2 | English |    70 |
|    3 | Chinese |    80 |
|    3 | English |    50 |
+------+---------+-------+
```

student

```
+------+----------+--------+
| ID   | CLASS_ID | NAME   |
+------+----------+--------+
|    1 |        1 | TOM    |
|    2 |        1 | ANNA   |
|    3 |        2 | JOHN   |
+------+----------+--------+
```

class

```
+------+----------+
| ID   | NAME     |
+------+----------+
|    1 | 5th      |
|    2 | 6th      |
+------+----------+
```

```
mysql> select class.NAME as CLASS_NAME, student.NAME from class inner join student on student.CLASS_ID = class.ID;
+------------+--------+
| CLASS_NAME | NAME   |
+------------+--------+
| 5th        | TOM    |
| 6th        | ANNA   |
| 6th        | JOHN   |
+------------+--------+

mysql> select SUM(SCORE) as total from score group by ID;
+-------+
| total |
+-------+
|   140 |
|   130 |
|   130 |
+-------+
```

Could I merge two select sentence let it be

```
+------------+--------+-------+
| CLASS_NAME | NAME   | total |
+------------+--------+-------+
| 5th        | TOM    |   140 |
| 6th        | ANNA   |   130 |
| 6th        | JOHN   |   130 |
+------------+--------+-------+
```

Or is there any better search sentence to do this well?

I try use two sentence to merge , but can't have a good idea.

```
mysql> select class.NAME as CLASS_NAME, student.NAME from class inner join student on student.CLASS_ID = class.ID;
mysql> select SUM(SCORE) as total from score group by ID;
```

hope it can be merge success or have another answer to do this well.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Do you have any **specific** question about this?

Comment: Use `JOIN` to combine the queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join to merge the second query. Below query takes in consideration that the join condition will be `score.id` with `student.id`

```
select c.name as class_name, 
       st.name ,
       sc.total
from class c
inner join student st on st.class_id = c.id
inner join ( select id,
                    SUM(SCORE) as total 
             from score 
             group by id
           ) as sc on sc.id=st.id ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/tauTGBFO